# How to test for highest value in JUnit

Tags: java, junit

I want to test to find the highest value.
Can find out the value using assertEquals?
getValue() is a getter to get Value.

```
public class TestGetHighestValue {
@Test
Value theValue = new Value();
public void test() {
    assertEquals();
}
```

Value class

```
public class Value{ 
public Value(){
}
public int getHighestValue() {
    int highestValue = this.firstStuff.getValue();
    int secondValue = this.secondStuff.getValue();
    int thirdValue = this.thirdStuff.getValue();

    if (highestValue < secondValue) {
        highestValue = secondValue;
    }

    if (highestValue < thirdValue) {
        highestValue = thirdValue;
    }

    return highestValue;
}
```

}

Comment: Well, you should know what the highest value is expected to be so just pass the value you got and the expected value. If you don't know what the highest value should be this might indicate a flaw with your tests.

Comment: I tried assertEquals(theValue.getFirstStuff.getValue(), theValue.getHightesValue()); but I got an Error

Comment: Please don't make us guess what error you got. When asking about an error or exception you should always tell us and post the description and if available the stacktrace. Also, do you _know_ that the first value should be the highest in your test?

Answer (score 3):

You can use Math in order to find max value.

```
public int getHighestValue() {
    return Math.max(firstStuff, secondStuff, thirdStuff);
}
```

You have to prepare the expected value.

```
Value value = new Value(1,2,3);
int expectedValue = 3;
assertEquals(expectedValue, value.getHighestValue());
```